# What is a suitable index for this query?

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

1. Below query is taking long time - around 540 seconds.
2. The table did not have any indexes. I created indexes on columns in the `WHERE` clause and other fields but the query is not using these indexes.
3. Please suggest good indexes for this query.

Query:

```
select
    alias_to,
    fake_uri,
    concat(ifnull(parameters,''),ifnull(parameters2,''),ifnull(parameters3,'')) as parameters,
    precedence,
    template_name
from site_map_template
order by precedence, fake_uri desc;
```

Explain output:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | site_map_template | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 7616 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

site_map_template table:

```
CREATE TABLE `site_map_template` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `template_name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `alias_to` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `package` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fake_uri` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `precedence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameters` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameters2` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameters3` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_1372` (`template_name`),
  KEY `idx_n1` (`precedence`),
  KEY `idx_n2` (`fake_uri`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
```

Comment: There is no `WHERE` clause in your query, and the `ORDER BY` specifies two columns which is not in your single index (idx_1372).

Comment: I was tried with single indexes and composite indexes on order by column but no luck.

Comment: Your table definition shows no sign of those indexes, I bet they don't exist.

Comment: Please find the updated structure.

Comment: What happens if you add a composite index of (precedence, fake_uri)?

Comment: when i was tried with composite index also but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7553/discussion-between-ashuthosh-and-dezso)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SQL Server 2012 (hopefully there is an equivalent in MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.site_map_template 
(
  row_mod datetime NULL,
  row_create datetime NULL,
  template_name varchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  alias_to varchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  package varchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  fake_uri varchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  precedence integer NULL,
  parameters1 varchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  parameters2 varchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL,
  parameters3 varchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NULL
);
```

A good clustered index for this query is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK__site_map_template_precedence_fake_uri
ON dbo.site_map_template (precedence, fake_uri DESC);
```

Or, a nonclustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc1
ON dbo.site_map_template
    (
    precedence,
    fake_uri DESC
    )
INCLUDE
    (
    alias_to,
    parameters1,
    parameters2,
    parameters3,
    template_name
    );
```

The query (again, in SQL Server syntax) is:

```
SELECT
    alias_to, 
    fake_uri,
    [parameters] = CONCAT(parameters1, parameters2, parameters3),
    precedence, 
    template_name 
FROM dbo.site_map_template
ORDER BY
    precedence, 
    fake_uri DESC;
```

And the execution plan is a simple scan of the index:

[image: Clustered index plan]

Or, using the nonclustered index:

[image: Nonclustered index plan]

The important thing in both cases is that each index covers all the columns needed by the query, and the index keys are precedence ASC and fake_uri **DESC**. Without the descending second key, a full sort would be required, and this is likely the cause of your slow performance.

Comment: MySQL (simple) indexes can be used for either `ASC` or `DESC` ordering. Unfortunately compound indexes will be useful only for `ASC, ASC` or `DESC, DESC` orderings. Mixed types will probably not use the index.